# Having n (2048 bit number), how can I find two numbers p and q that satisfy n = p*q, where p = r||s (r and s concatenated) and q = s||r?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa, factors

I'm using the RSA encryption/decryption system, and I have the modulus n (which is a 2048 bit number) and I need to find p and q, which satisfy n = p*q and both are prime numbers. The clue that is given to me is that p is equal to q but with its bits inverted as I say in the title of this post (concretely r and s have the same bits so we could say that p and q have their halves inverted). I don't find the way to take advantage of this so I would be very grateful if someone could help me

I have tried to traverse the number n to find the number p that satisfies that p * p_halfs_inverted = n but logically n is too huge and it is not viable to do it in this way.

Comment: What happens when you calculate `((r * s) << 1024) + ((r^2 + s^2) << 512) + (r * s)`? Is there any information you can extract from the result? Since this looks like a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1679849), I'll leave you to figure out the details.

Comment: To add a little to the previous comment, one way to express the concatenation operation r || s mathematically is r * 2^k + s, for 2^(k-1) <= s < 2^k.

Comment: @r3mainer thanks to your comment and President James K. Polk comment I see that n should equal ((r * s) << 1024) + ((r^2 + s^2) << 512) + (r * s), but since then I have an equation with r and s unknown, for now I don't find the way to find p and q.

Comment: @Javier Pick some values for `r` and `s` and perform some calculations yourslf. For example, compare the hex values of `n` and `r * s`. Can you see any similarities?

Comment: @r3mainer the numbers that I have to generate need 512 bits? I have generated a couple and I see no similarities with n, they only have 2 positions != 0 in hexadecimal

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk should I try values in the range 2^(k-1) <= s < 2^k and the same for r?

Comment: @Javier: I don't actually know the answer but I'd go with r3mainer's hints. It appears that the low-order 512 bits are only a function of r * s. It also appears that high-order bits beyond bit 1536 or so are also only a function of r*s except with perhaps a carry from the lower-order bits. So my instinct is to try and guess some of the bits of r and s separately and see if there is some way to reject some of the wrong guesses. Beyond that it just amounts to staring, experimenting, thinking, and repeating until a solution comes to you. Sometimes a wrong path will lead you to the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

OK here's how you can solve this problem.

Start by representing *p* and *q* in terms of two *k*-bit numbers *r* and *s* as follows (for your example, *k*=512):

> *p* = 2<sup>*k*</sup>*r* + *s*
> *q* = 2<sup>*k*</sup>*s* + *r*

The value of *n* is the product of these two numbers:

> *n*   =   *pq*   =   (2<sup>*k*</sup>*r* + *s*)(2<sup>*k*</sup>*s* + *r*)   =   2<sup>2*k*</sup>*rs* + 2<sup>*k*</sup>(*r*<sup>2</sup> + *s*<sup>2</sup>) + *rs*

The first two terms on the right are both multiples of 2<sup>*k*</sup>, so the *k* lowest bits of *n* are exactly equal to the *k* lowest bits of *rs*. Furthermore, since *rs* is typically a 2*k*-bit number and *r*<sup>2</sup> + *s*<sup>2</sup> is typically a (2*k*+1)-bit number, the *k* highest bits of *n* are also *mostly* equal to the *k* highest bits of *rs*, but perhaps slightly larger due to the carry generated when adding the 2<sup>*k*</sup>(*r*<sup>2</sup> + *s*<sup>2</sup>) term.

If *n*<sub>◁</sub> and *n*<sub>▷</sub> are numbers representing the top *k* bits and bottom *k* bits of *n*, then we can generate a candidate value for *rs* by calculating 2<sup>*k*</sup>*n*<sub>◁</sub> + *n*<sub>▷</sub>. If this value is correct, we can subtract (2<sup>2*k*</sup> + 1)*rs* from *n* to obtain the value of 2<sup>*k*</sup>(*r*<sup>2</sup> + *s*<sup>2</sup>). Divide this result by 2<sup>*k*</sup> and add 2*rs* to obtain *r*<sup>2</sup> + 2*rs* + *s*<sup>2</sup>, then calculate the square root of this value to obtain the value of *r* + *s*. (If the number isn't a perfect square, then you need to subtract 1 from *n*<sub>◁</sub> and try again.

After at most two iterations of this process, you will have the exact values of *rs* and *r*+*s*. You should then have no difficulty solving a simultaneous equation to obtain values for *r* and *s*, from which you can find *p* and *q*.

Note: You might find the `sympy.sqrt()` function useful for calculating square roots of large numbers. It returns objects with an `is_integer` attribute that will tell you if the number you provided was a perfect square.